# Alternative for View Filter Block for Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am looking for a way to get the same functionality as "Views Filter Block" ( see http://drupal.org/project/views_filterblock) but for Drupal 6. Taken from the description:

> "The views_filterblock module basically moves the horizontal filter from the views page content area into a (vertical) block."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go in and edit a block - look in the first column on the left, and find the item marked 'Exposed form in block'.  Click on that and set it to yes.

Bing!  Done.